# the custom menubar isn't showing on a mac?

Tags: javascript, electron

The developer `menubar` is showing instead of my custom menubar and I did add empty object in the `menuTemplate` and still not working.

I'm using a mac

I've tried to set the menu of the browser window to null
and still not showing my custom `menubar`

```
const electron = require('electron');
const{app,BrowserWindow,Menu} = electron;
const url = require("url");
const path = require("path")

let mainWindow;
let addWindow;
app.on('ready', function(){
  mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({});
  mainWindow.loadURL(url.format({
    pathname: path.join(__dirname, "index.html"),
    protocol: 'file: ',
    slashes: true
  }));

  const mainMenu = Menu.buildFromTemplate(menuTemplate);
  Menu.setApplicationMenu(mainMenu);
});

function createAddWindow(){
  addWindow = new BrowserWindow({
    width: 300,
    height: 200,
    title: " Add shopping list item"
  });
  addWindow.loadURL(url.format({
    pathname: path.join(__dirname, "subwindow.html"),
    protocol: 'file: ',
    slashes: true
  }));
}
// create menu template
const menuTemplate = [
  {},
  {
    Label: "file",
    submenu:[
      {
        Label: "add item",
        click(){
          createAddWindow();
        }
      },{
        Label: "clear items"
      },{
        label: "quit",
        accelerator: process.platform == "darwin" ? 'Command+Q' : 'Ctrl+Q',
        click(){
          app.quit();
        }
      }]
  }
]
```

I want to show my custom `menubar`.

Answer (score 0):

Your menu template causes errors for me on startup (Electron 4.1.3 on Ubuntu).

I removed the empty object at index 0 and changed `Label` to `label`. Also, I think you can simply use `CmdOrCtrl` for the accelerator.

```
const menuTemplate = [
  {
    label: "file",
    submenu: [
      {
        label: "add item",
        click(){
          createAddWindow();
        }
      },{
        label: "clear items"
      },{
        label: "quit",
        accelerator: 'CmdOrCtrl+Q',
        click(){
          app.quit();
        }
      }]
  }
]
```

This results in the following menu:

[image: Screenshot of the menu]

Comment: Yes, see the screenshot that I added to the answer.

Comment: i did exactly what you have said and still showing the dev menubar

Comment: I tried this code on my windows computer and it shows nothing  not even the dev menubar

Comment: Which Electron version are you using? Are you using exactly the code from the question?

Comment: Yes, I’m using 4.1.2v